# 2016 AMC 10A #18 — Number of ways to label vertices of acube

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory

> Each vertex of a cube is to be labeled with an integer $1$ through $8$, with each integer being used once, in such a way that the sum of the four numbers on the vertices of a face is the same for each face. Arrangements that can be obtained from each other through rotations of the cube are considered to be the same. How many different arrangements are possible?

The solutions for this problem at AoPS all essentially involve guess and check. However, similar problems of this nature can usually be solved using Burnside's Lemma.

Is there a way to solve this more efficient than guess and check, perhaps using Burnside's lemma?

--

In my attempt at a solution I gathered the following facts.

1) The number of rotational symmetries of a cube is 24.

2) The sum on each face must be 18.

3) [I think] the arrangement of numbers on the top face of the cube uniquely determine the arrangement on the bottom face.

4) Given the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8} if you choose four numbers to be top face such that they sum to 18, the remaining four (the complement) will also sum to 18 and can be considered to be the bottom face.

So the problem (I think) boils down to finding the number of solutions of $a + b + c + d = 18$ where each of $a, b, c, d$ is unique and between $1$ and $8$.

I'm not sure how to solve this equation, however (it looks similar but doesn't seem to be reducible to the stars-and-bars type of combinatorial problem that is standard for such equations).

Comment: The difficult thing, I think, is accounting for rotation overcounts.

Comment: https://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=2016_AMC_10A_Problems/Problem_18. You will find a full solution along the lines of what you are looking for here.

Comment: @Αδριανός In the body of my question I noted that the solutions at AoPS are more bash-y. I am asking if there is any clever synthetic way to solve this.

Comment: @1110101001 Oh I see; I did not notice that and jumped straight to the heart of the problem. I do not believe there is a better trick to it than doing it manually, though I may very well be wrong.